# add toolbar menu only at specific fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

So I have this app and in the toolbar, there is a drop-down menu and I am looking for a solution on how to show only specific items at specific fragments.

I know that I have to make a java class and link it to the menu, but how do I find out what fragment I am on?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the implementation of setting the toolbar for your fragments in the activity that launches these fragments. In that case, you may have the toolbar in your activity and the activity should have a fragment container where you will put your fragment. Let us consider a layout like the following for your activity.

```
<RelativeLayout> 

    <!-- Your toolbar here in the activity -->
    <ToolBar>
        android:id="+@id/toolbar"
        ...
    </ToolBar> 

    <!-- Your fragment container here -->
    <FrameLayout>
        android:id="+@id/fragment_container"
        ...
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, you have the `ToolBar` here in your activity and hence, you can set the toolbar when you are loading the fragments in the fragment container. Your activity might have the following functions.

```
public void launchFrag1() {

    // replace the fragment 1 in the fragment container
    loadToolbarForFrag1();
}

public void launchFrag2() {

    // replace the fragment 2 in the fragment container
    loadToolbarForFrag2();
}
```

Now call the specific function of your activity to load the fragment and the toolbar dynamically as well.

If you are trying to call the method from the fragment, you can always call those methods declared in your activity like the following.

```
((YourActivity) getActivity()).launchFrag2();
```

I hope you get the idea.

Please note that this is just a basic implementation of how you can get your dynamic toolbar working in your app. However, your implementation might vary based on the use case that you have.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have an ImageView in the toolbar which I hide as follows:

```
  // Show image in fragment 1
  ImageView img = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbarMenu);
 img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

 // hide image in fragment 2
ImageView img = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbarMenu);
 img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Try these codes in onCreateView after inflating your layout